# php-cli outputs instead of executing

Tags: php

Im using Debian testing, i have installed php-cli and when i try to execute a php script it output the source instead of executing it.

Example:

```
 php test.php
 <?
 phpinfo();
 ?>
```

any ideas how to fix this behavior, i tried reinstalling and purging no results.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Find following line in your php.ini file:
short_open_tag = Off

And change it to:
short_open_tag = On

Comment: short_open_tags are deprecated for a reason

Answer (score 10):

Change `<?` to `<?php`. [Short tags](http://www.bin-co.com/php/articles/using_php_short_tags.php) must not be enabled.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you have [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/ini.core#ini.short-open-tag) turned off.

Either change that configuration option or, preferably, use the full opening tag: `<?php`